# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. while using Function app and Azure SQL Server using MSI

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-function-app, azure-managed-identity

I have a function app which is time triggered only `once` per day.
It connects to `Azure SQL Server` using `Managed Service Identity (MSI)`.

I am creating `SqlConnection` object in the static constructor. I am setting AccessToken to the `SqlConnection` object using

```
new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString)
        {
            // AzureServiceTokenProvider handles caching the token and refreshing it before it expires
            AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result
        };
```

Every time I `restart` the `Function App`, it works fine. But from the next day (24 hours later) I get the error `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.`
It works intermittently (once in few days).

Exception Call Stack

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
   at Microsoft.SupplyChain.Dependency.AutofacInterceptionLogBehavior.Intercept (Microsoft.SupplyChain.Dependency, Version=1.22019.1206.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed (Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc)
   at Castle.Proxies.IUoWProxy.ExecuteQuery (DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at DataIngestor.Foo+<Update>d__11.MoveNext (DataIngestor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at DataIngestor.Foo+<Run>d__5.MoveNext (DataIngestor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullIDataHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\MasterData\PartNumberIngestion\DataHandler\Foo.csDataIngestor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 135)
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi are you still looking for help on this

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I am not getting this error again, but I started getting error mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809422/login-failed-for-user-token-identified-principal-token-is-expired-when-usin

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation