# Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired when using Azure Function app and Azure SQL Service using Managed Identity

Tags: c#, azure-function-app, azure-sql-server, azure-managed-identity

I am using a function app which is service bus triggered. It connects to `Azure SQL Server` using `Managed Identity`.

The connection is created using the following code.

```
new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString)
        {
            // AzureServiceTokenProvider handles caching the token and refreshing it before it expires
            AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result
        };
```

I get a few thousand events every day, and all these are failing on connecting to the database.

The stack trace from our logs is

```
[{"parsedStack":[{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor","level":0,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection","level":1,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection","level":2,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject","level":3,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest","level":4,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection","level":5,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection","level":6,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection","level":7,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal","level":8,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection","level":9,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen","level":10,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open","level":11,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection","level":12,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open","level":13,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext","level":14,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute","level":15,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+Enumerator.MoveNext","level":16,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider+<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext","level":17,"line":0},
{"assembly":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor`1+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext","level":18,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Linq, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext","level":19,"line":0},
{"assembly":"System.Linq, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst","level":20,"line":0},
{"assembly":"MaskedProjectPNameIngestor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"MaskedProjectPNameIngestor.SRFunction.RetrieveCodeAsync","level":21,"line":182,"fileName":"D:\\a\\1\\s\\MaskedProject\\PNameIngestion\\MaskedProjectPNameIngestor\\SRFunction.cs"},
{"assembly":"MaskedProjectPNameIngestor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"MaskedProjectPNameIngestor.SRFunction+<Run>d__5.MoveNext","level":22,"line":121,"fileName":"D:\\a\\1\\s\\MaskedProject\\PNameIngestion\\MaskedProjectPNameIngestor\\SRFunction.cs"}],
"outerId":"0","message":"Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired.","type":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","id":"64152618"}]
```

Appreciate any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Does my answer help your question?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/securing-azure-sql-databases-with-managed-identities-just-got-easier/

Comment: Is my answer useful to you, do you need further help?

Comment: @JasonPan, Apologies for the late reply. My trouble is that I have done all of what you have mentioned, but still facing this issue.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you follow my answer, you can get the correct result, which is fully shown in my screenshots. Make sure your code is consistent with mine, and there is still an error. You may need to raise a support ticket on the portal.

Comment: It is recommended to recreate and operate step by step according to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need `CREATE USER <Azure_AD_principal_name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;` in Azure SQL Server.You can see [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell).

And you also need to open `Identity` status `On` in portal.

My Result.

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace func_sqlcon
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
        {
            var str = "Server=tcp:*********.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=********;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");
            string AccessToken;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str);
            try
            {
                AccessToken = await (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", "e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb");
                connection.AccessToken = AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            connection.Open();
            return new OkObjectResult(AccessToken);
        }
    }
}
```