# sqlalchemy Azure SQL Token Authentication Failure

Tags: pandas, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

We are trying to connect and insert data into our AZURE SQL DB using sqlalchemy and pandas.dataframe.to_sql using our service principal and token. The problem is that we are able to connect to one database perfectly but to another database we are getting the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. (18456)") (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

We are trying to login via Service Principal using client id, client secret & Tenant ID. All the values have been verified and are working fine to connect to the database using Azure databricks.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that we are able to connect to one database perfectly but to another database, we are getting the `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'` error.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell&view=azuresql#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities), if you are using any external provider then you need to create and map the required permissions to Azure AD identities.

```
CREATE USER <Azure_AD_principal_name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
CREATE USER [bob@contoso.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
CREATE USER [alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

And after that, as suggested by [Jason Pan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809422/login-failed-for-user-token-identified-principal-token-is-expired-when-usin) , make sure to `On` Identity status on portal.

**Updated answer**:

According to [Radiatelabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4887542/radiatelabs), the issue got fixed after copying the whole database from DEV to UAT and creating the UAT user in the database.

References: [Login Failed for user ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/133709/login-failed-for-user-39lttoken-identified-princip.html), [Login failed for user token-identified principal when web app is in an AAD Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494736/login-failed-for-user-token-identified-principal-when-web-app-is-in-an-aad-g) ,and [Login failed for user 'token-identified principal' but works in Data Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173552/login-failed-for-user-token-identified-principal-but-works-in-data-studio)

Comment: Thanks but I think there was issue with the user/permissions that I was trying to connect with, its strange I tried to recreate the AAD User but still it didn't work. Then I copied the whole database from DEV to UAT and created the UAT user in the database and IT WORKED!!

Comment: Glad to know that it's been fixed. Updated the answer.